# Why Does Url Decode a Backslash into 2 Backslashes

Tags: c#, url, decode, encode, urldecode

I am trying to decode a url encoding. However, during testing I saw that the encoding of a backslash `\` which is `%5C` will get decoded into `\\`. Why is that? How can I make it just one backslash without replacing it manually?

This is my code:

```
string decodedValue = Uri.UnescapeDataString(articleNr);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are viewing the value of backslash in a debugger rather than printing it out. Since the backslash is a special escaping character, the debugger shows it as `\\` but it's `\` in the actual value.

```
Console.WriteLine(Uri.UnescapeDataString("%5C")); // prints \
```

Comment: You are right! My bad, I was confused why it doesn't display it properly. I will accept it as the answer in 10 minutes since I am not allowed yet.